# Javascript variable incrementing in evaluation?

Tags: javascript

If I have

```
a = 0;
if(a++ < 1){
    console.log(a);
}
```

I get the value 1 in the console. If a became 1 with the incrementation, then why did the expression evaluate true?

If I do

```
a = 0;
if(++a < 1){
    console.log(a);
}
```

Then I don't get anything in the console, meaning the expression evaluated to be false.

I have always used `variable++` to increment variables in for loops and the like. I have seen the `++variable`, but I assumed it was another way to write the same thing. Can someone explain what happens and why? What's the difference between the two?

Does `++variable` increment the variable at the time of evaluation, while `variable++` increments after?

Comment: @See [MDN Arithmetic Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Comment: This has been asked and answered many, many times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have seen the `++variable`, but I assumed it was another way to write the same thing.

No, they're not the same at all.

- `++variable` is **pre**-increment.
  It increments `variable` and evaluates to the new value.
- `variable++` is **post**-increment.
  It increments `variable` and evaluates to the old value.

This is common to most C-style languages, including C itself, C++, PHP, Java and Javascript.

i.e.:

> Does `++variable` increment the variable at the time of evaluation, while `variable++` increments after?

Yes, exactly. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a very important difference here. `a++` increments a *after* evaluation, where `++a` increments *before* evaluation. Conveniently the position of the `++` is either before or after as well, so that's how you can remember which is which.

In other words, this is what you're effectively doing:

```
a = 0;
if (a < 1)
{
   a = a + 1;
   console.log(a);
}
else
{
   a = a + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is post incrementing, so for the comparison it is `0`, then in the block statement it is `1`.

```
a = 0;

// v-----0 < 1
if(a++ < 1){
      // now a has been incremented to 1
    console.log(a);
}
```

The pre incrementing version looks like:

```
a = 0;

//   v-----1 < 1
if(++a < 1){
      // evaluate to false, so this doesn't run
    console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`++var` adds one, then does the comparison.

`var++` does the comparison, then adds one.

The trick is to remember it by the `++` coming before the variable (increment happens before), or after the variable (increment happens after).